# Verbs joined with くて and modifying a noun

Tags: grammar, relative-clauses

I understand that くて joins verbs but what happens if they modify a noun? For example:

お金がなくて食べない料理 - I don't have money and hence this is food that I won't eat

見た目がなくて届かない想い - I don't have the looks and hence it is an unreachable feeling

Is this a valid sentence grammatically?

Comment: I think 見た目がなくて would mean in this context "I haven't experienced *something*".  So your second example seems to say "ideas that don't reach beyond what's been experienced".  And without any further context, the first example seems to be talking about the sort of food you eat when you don't have any money.

Comment: Which is "a noun modifier" in your examples? 料理 is not a modifier, but is a noun **modified** by a relative clause. Did you want to say "what happens if the くて-joined sentences modify a noun as relative clauses"?

Comment: @naruto Wrong term used. I meant modified noun rather than noun modifier. For example, 届かない modifies the noun 想い

Answer (score 2):

## Japanese

結論から言うと

> お金がなくて食べない料理
>
> 見た目がなくて届かない想い

両方とも文章としておかしいです。ただ、最初の方はなんとなく意味はわかりますが2番目の方は意味がわかりません。
解決するためにそれぞれの文を分解します。

> お金がなくて食べない料理

この文は「お金がない」と「食べない料理」に分けられます。ここでポイントとなるのが「食べない料理」です。
この場合、お金がないので**食べることができない**と考えるのでより良い文は

「お金がなくて食べられない料理」

です。

次に

> 見た目がなくて届かない想い

この文は「見た目がない」と「届かない想い」に分けることができます。ここでのポイントは「見た目がない」の意味がわからないことです。

もしuser40637さんの言うとおり

> 見た目が良くないので、想いを届けられない

だとしたら文法として問題ないです。

ちなみに

> 見た目が良くないので想いを届けられない
>
> 見た目が良くなくて想いを届けられない
>
> 見た目が悪くて想いを届けられない

は同じ意味です。

## English

My answer is

> お金がなくて食べない料理
>
> 見た目がなくて届かない想い

both are grammatically wrong. But we can catch what the first sentence wants to tell, on the other hand, the second doesn't make sense.

I break them apart into two in order to make the problems clear.

First,

> お金がなくて食べない料理

Let's break this into "お金がない" and "食べない料理". A problem is "食べない料理".
In this context, I think a man doesn't have money so **cannot afford to buy** food. So the better sentence is

「お金がなくて食べられない料理」.

Next,

> 見た目がなくて届かない想い

this can be "見た目がない" and "届かない想い". The important thing is that "見た目がない" doesn't make sense.

If it's, as user40637 mentioned above,

> 見た目が良くないので、想いを届けられない

, the sentence is correct.

By the way,

> 見た目が良くないので想いを届けられない
>
> 見た目が良くなくて想いを届けられない
>
> 見た目が悪くて想いを届けられない

all of them mean same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Grammatically OK.
It seems like s strange expression from the context.I cannot make proper meaning out.

お金がなくて食べない料理 >should be wrote> お金がなくて食べられない料理

見た目がなくて届かない想い >should be wrote> 見た目が良くないので、想いを届けられない。(You cannot say your thinking since your look is not good.)
or
見た目がなくて届かない想い >should be wrote> 見た目が良くないので、想いが届かない。(Someone rejects your thinking since your look is not good.)